# Sometimes when I edit my-CV, it puts the wrong values into the wrong fields

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs

Sometimes when I click the "edit cv" tab on http://careers.stackoverflow.com, it will not properly fill the fields.

Under Technology Preference, the Favourite textbox will hold the values of "Job Title" on my first experience item.

I have no idea how to recreate this, it does not happen every single time.

If it helps, I'm using:

1. Chrome (developer stream, and maybe that is the problem(?))
2. Win-XP

Answer (score 1):

We've definitely seen issues with developer releases of Chrome in the past.

**We only support officialy "final" releases of browsers. Anything else is at your own risk..**

Marking declined, unless you can repro with Chrome 3 release version.

Comment: It might be worth putting this into the FAQ, along with a link to how to file bugs against Chrome :)

Comment: Chrome (Ubuntu karmic) here. Same issue -- some fields are being overwritten with values elseware on the page. 

If this is an incompatibility or bug with Chrome, there should be a warning on the edit page itself (surely enough people come to the site in chrome to warrant something like that?).

Comment: @seth we only support final releases of browsers, so you use Chrome v4 (unreleased) at your own risk

Comment: isn't those who are adventurous enough to use Chrome v4 are the very people that you want them to sign up Careers? Why you can't just reward them by fixing the problem?